# How to get the Joomla-3.x pagination prev/next link with the getData() function in the content plugin like onContentPrepare

Tags: joomla-3.x, pagination

How do I get the Joomla-3.x pagination prev/next link, using the `getData()` function, in the content plugin with the `onContentPrepare` event?

What is the work of `$limitstart` here: `onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked close enough to verify, but you might want to have a look at:

```
$article->pagination
```

print_r that bad-boy to see what's in it.  I believe that's going to contain the links you're looking for.

onContentPrepare $limitstart designated which page of a paginated article to start on.  If you've used pagebreaks, this is used.  Convenient if you want your content plugin to run on only certain pages.

Comment: I want to get the pagination in the $view == 'category'. For example, if there is more pages then set metadata. Else in the first page set metadata. Also get the prev/next page. $this->pagination->getData() works in the article component category view. How to get this from the content plugin.

Comment: That makes things tougher, because the content plugins work on each individual article, not on the category itself (maybe in the category description though...)

I'll have a closer look at this tonight.  I'm sure something can be found.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments name is "page" not "limitstart". From the docs it mans:
*"An integer that determines the "page" of the content that is to be generated. Note that in the context of views that might not generate HTML output, a page is a reasonably abstract concept that depends on the context."*

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content